# Get a list of users in a socket.io chat

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I'm currently working on a socket.io based chat application.

I found a LOT of tutorials on how to manage messages, but I'm struggling with the users list.

I'd like to display a list of connected users, with a few twists:

- When a user joins the chat, he has to pick a name
- Once he has picked a name, he can talk, and see a list with the names of other users

I'm struggling with this last part: for the messages, its quite easy, I can fetch the existing messages in my database. But how can I retrieve and display the list of connected users ?

I tried with the following pieceo f cade, in my react application:

```
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([])
  const [step, setStep] = useState('lobby')
  const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);

  useEffect(() => {

    socket.emit('data', {
      type: 'joinedRoom',
    })

    socket.on("FromAPI", data => {
      if (data.type === 'newPlayer') {

        setPlayers([{
          name: data.payload.name,
        }])
      }
      if (data.type === 'joinedRoom') {
        socket.emit('data', {
          type: 'getPlayers',
          players,
        })
      }

      if (data.type === 'getPlayers') {
        if (data.players && data.players.length) {
          setPlayers([...players, data.players])
        }
      }

    });
```

But this doesn't work: for any new user, the `players` state fragment is initialized as an empty array.

I'm fairly new to websockets in general, any help about how to handle data-sharing would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using nodejs on your backend?,if so than u can either create a users arrry,and push new user into tht array when ever a new user is connected.thn u can access tht anytime,dont forget to delete user whn disconnected